# xamarin.oauth /xamarin forms Facebook linkedin google authentification

Tags: visual-studio, oauth, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am new in Xamarin   ,I am looking for a way to put facebook/linkedin/google authentication. I have looked at many tutorials but none of them is  recent and there are not working well or there are obsolete.

Here is the tutorials, I have found: [click to seeing the page](http://xamarininterviewquestion.blogspot.fr/2016/09/oauth-login-authenticating-with.html)

Do you know a recent and  better one ?

Comment: @LandLu-MSFT  still not...

Answer (score 1):

There are many samples about how to authenticate users in facebook or google. And I find your article [here](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Auth-Login-Authenticating-ef41cf0c) in MSDN with a sample which runs in VS2015. Even though it's a little bit out of date, you can also find something useful.

You can also refer to the official documentation of [Xamarin.OAuth](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/authentication/oauth/) and the sample [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WebServices/OAuthNativeFlow/). Modify the information in `Constants` to your own's. This article specify how to register in Google and get the `Client ID` and `Redirect URL`.

You can read it more carefully then create your own UI to achieve authentication.